# Has anyone seen a dataset break after adding a new tableadapter?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a dataset in a project which I'm using to provide databinding for winforms controls.  Everything has been working fine (tableadapters with select, insert, update, delete methods provided by stored procedures) until I added another tableadapter this morning.

Since adding it, every tableadapter in the dataset broke.  My project now has 63 errors reporting errors along the lines of :

Error   60  The type name 'SelectCompanyStatusesDataTable' does not exist in the type '..Search.Presentation.dsSearchTableAdapters.dsSearch'  C:\Data\Visual Studio Projects\.\..Search.Presentation\dsSearch.Designer.cs 32210   33  ..Search.Presentation

(Using  and  to censor sensitive names)

I'm at a complete loss with regards to what has gone wrong, let alone how to fix it.

I'm wondering, has anyone seen anything like this happen before and maybe provide a few pointers for what direction I shoulod be looking in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only encountered this after an unsuccessful attempt to rename a dataset's namespace -- the namespace and classnames in the auto-generated and manually generated partial classes didn't match.
In the end I went for a scorched-earth policy and created a new dataset with a slightly different name, and used cut and paste to get the items of the designer in the original into the new dataset.  I then deleted the original and updated all references to use the new one.

Comment: That worked, thanks :-)
Still not sure why it went wrong, maybe something interrupted it when it was rebuilding the designer.cs file?  Anyway, at least it's sorted

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but this just happened to me and I managed to fix all the compile errors by clearing out the MyDataSet.cs file (**not** the MyDataSet.Designer.cs file).

The MyDataSet.Designer.cs file has the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  [.....]
  public partial class MyDataSet : global::System.Data.DataSet {
.
.
.
```

and the MyDataSet.cs file is usually empty (from looking at an old version). But for some reason (I think maybe double-clicking in the dataset designer while adding a new tableadapter), the MyDataSet.cs file had the following contents:

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyDataSetTableAdapters {
  public partial class MyDataSet {
  }
}
```

which, as you can see, doesn't match up with the definition in MyDataSet.Designers.cs.

Clearing MyDataSet.cs removed all the 'The type name 'MyDataTable' does not exist in the type MyNamespace.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyDataSet' errors.

I know this is old but I found this by googling so hopefully it'll help someone else out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...this just happened to me as well.
I used the rightclick "rename" on the dataset.xsd to rename a datatable and adapter.

Blew everything away.

bummer....last couple hours gone.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the connection string in the project settings changes, before a schema modification too. I know because it happened many times where I worked. I am an expert at fixing data-sets and also know some run-time work-rounds.